# AKS template creates new resource groups

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-aks

When I create an AKS cluster using Azure portal I can see that new resource groups are created. It seems that I have no control over how they are named, especially the one with with "MC_" prefix. I also don't see an option to change its name when using ARM template.

In addition, if I create a cluster in customer's subscription, where I only have access to 1 resource group, I don't even see the newly created RG and can't manage it.

Is there a way to force deployment of all AKS components into a single resource group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>No, there is no way to force it at this point in time</strike>. As for the access, you should request access to that RG. No real workarounds.

Secondary resource group name can be inferred, I think, its something like:

```
MC_original-resource-group-name_aks-resource-name_location
```

it also creates OMS resource group (if you enable OMS) and Network Watcher (this can be disabled, btw, but its a provider setting). you have no control over that as well.

there is a not implemented yet nodeResourceGroup property:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/createorupdate#examples

EDIT: this is actually working right now, so the nodeResourceGroup property can be used. But it would still be a new resource group, so you would still need to request access to that group and using this property is not possible with the portal (so ARM Templates\pulumi\terraform)

Comment: Is it safe to move all resources from the MC_*  to the orignal-resource-group after cluster creation?

Comment: no, that wont work (that will, but AKS wont work after that), you might want to look at AKS engine, it allows to customize everything, more or less (but you pay for and manage master nodes)

Comment: I've spent a few weeks trying to figure out how to see the resources in the Resource Group that AKS created. While this isn't the answer I wanted, at least it will save me the pain of continuing to look. This question was asked over a year ago, though. Any chance there's a better answer now? If not, please consider voting on my Azure feedback post:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/40132615-create-a-role-that-allows-for-propagation-of-permi

Comment: @4c74356b41, thanks for the response, but I think this still isn't want I need. My problem is that I'm still in the R&D phase, and I'm creating and destroying the cluster multiple times per day. Even though the resource group name is predictable, I think every time it's created, it gets a new ID -- so I think that means that I'd need to request access to it every time I create it. I really, really hope they implement a feature that propagates permissions to all Resource Groups that are created as a result of actions you take (eg: creating an AKS cluster).

Comment: well, tbh, i dont know why you need access to that rg? kbuernetes does everything for you